# How would one draw an arbitrary curve in createJS

Tags: createjs

I am attempting to write a function using createJS to draw an arbitrary function and I'm having some trouble. I come from a d3 background so I'm having trouble breaking out of the data-binding mentality.

Suppose I have 2 arrays `xData = [-10, -9, ... 10]` and `yData = Gaussian(xData)` which is psuedocode for mapping each element of `xData` to its value on the bell curve. How can I now draw yData as a function of xData?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To graph an arbitrary function in CreateJS, you draw lines connecting all the data points you have. Because, well, that's what graphing is!

The easiest way to do this is a for loop going through each of your data points, and calling a `lineTo()` for each. Because the canvas drawing API starts a line where you last 'left off', you actually don't even need to specify the line start for each line, but you DO have to move the canvas 'pen' to the first point before you start drawing. Something like:

```
// first make our shape to draw into. 
let graph = new createjs.Shape();
let g = graph.graphics
g.beginStroke("#000");

xStart = xData[0];
yStart = yourFunction(xData[0]);
g.moveTo(xStart, yStart);

for( let i = 1; i < xData.length; i++){
      nextX = xData[i], but normalized to fit on your graph area;
      nextY = yourFunction(xData[i]), but similarly normalized;
      g.lineTo(nextX, nextY);
}
```

This should get a basic version of the function drawing! Note that the line will be pretty jagged if you don't have a lot of data points, and you'll have to treat (normalize) your data to make it fit onto your screen. For instance, if you start at -10 for X, that's off the screen to the left by 10 pixels - and if it only runs from -10 to +10, your entire graph will be squashed into only 20 pixels of width.

I have a codepen showing this approach to graphing [here](https://codepen.io/balud/pen/BwXQRM). It's mapped to hit every pixel on the viewport and calculate a Y value for it, though, rather than your case where you have input X values. And FYI, the code for graphing is all inside the 'run' function at the top - everything in the PerlinNoiseMachine class is all about data generation, so you can ignore it for the purposes of this question.

Hope that helps! If you have any specific follow-up questions or code samples, please amend your question.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I tried, it turned out that I didn't account for transforming the data point from the cartesian coordinate space that exists in my head to the canvas space. Accounting for that this works like a charm. It seems strange to me that a `for loop` of really the best approach. Is there no higher level way?

Comment: Since this is a pretty simple approach, there is no mechanism in EaselJS to do it automatically. There _is_ a `decodePath`, which kind of does it, but uses a Base64-encoded path. This support was added specifically to make Adobe Animate path data more compact.